# Accessing Cloud Storage from Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I've been unable to find any concrete documentation on how to use Cloud Storage from an Android application.

I did come across [this client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) from the Google Cloud SDK, however have run into many, many issues and have yet to get it working.

I added the following code as recommended in the above link:

***build.gradle***:

```
compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-storage', version: '0.9.3-beta'
```

I then added some simple code, though this isn't really relevant to this question as I have yet been able to run my application with the above dependency added:

***In an Activity:***

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Page<Bucket> buckets = storage.list();
Iterator<Bucket> bucketIterator = buckets.iterateAll();
while (bucketIterator.hasNext()) {
    Bucket bucket = bucketIterator.next();
    Log.d(TAG, "Bucket name: " + bucket.getName());
}
```

After solving a myriad of dependency issues (Conflicts with Joda, Netty, `DuplicateFileException`'s from gradle, etc.) I was able to build the project, albeit with the below errors:

`Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.`
`Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20151123 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.`

I can then try running, which will fail with a few hundred errors, most of which look something like the following:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter$3) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

After quite a few of those, with varying classnames, the end of the error contains this:

> trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
>
> Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when
>   not building a core library.
>
> This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file in
>   your application's project, when using an IDE (such as Eclipse). If
>   you are sure you're not intentionally defining a core class, then this
>   is the most likely explanation of what's going on.
>
> However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
>   namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a
>   non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not
>   work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with
>   future versions of the platform. It is also often of questionable
>   legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help you in this endeavor.
>   If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an indication that
>   the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain, suffering, grief,
>   and lamentation.

A few questions:

1. Is this client library the correct way to access my Google Cloud Storage from my Android application?
2. Is there a reason I shouldn't try to access Cloud Storage from the mobile application? For example, would a better architecture be to make a REST API call to my App Engine application (using Cloud Enpoints) and pass it media objects, then have the App Engine app access and store the media in Cloud Storage, before finally returning the result to the mobile app?
3. If I am accessing Cloud Storage correctly, using the mentioned client library, what do these errors mean, and what it the fix?

Comment: What is your use case? The correct access method depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: At this point I'd settle for any type of connection to my Cloud Storage. As shown in the code snippet, I was simply trying to list bucket names. My "end" use-case will be to upload/download videos.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't write directly to Cloud Storage from client applications that can't be trusted with your security tokens. It sounds like you are not planning on authenticating directly as the user, but rather generally with your own project.

If you are not planning on doing a user-based OAuth2 flow (user must have their own Cloud Console project already with Storage enabled), then you're looking instead at proxying the requests through your own backend such as App Engine.

This approach keeps your storage credentials stored safely on the server side rather than in the client app's APK, which could be torn down, extracted, and then malicious actors could use those credentials to write to your buckets in whatever manner they chose. Oh and buckets and storage are a billable resource so exposing those credentials could cost you.

This is a common pattern for many cloud services from mobile that you're going to want to instead route requests through your own backend or API.

Comment: So you are saying I need to make a request to an App Engine app which in turn communicates with Cloud Storage? It does not make sense that communicating directly to Cloud Storage from a mobile application is not possible. For example, Firebase Storage is backend by Cloud Storage, and yet I can upload and download objects straight from the mobile application. Given your answer, how is that not a security concern?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying if you are going with Cloud Storage. Firebase Storage handles security using Firebase Authentication for Android, which relies on the Android auth mechanisms I believe that reside in the GMS core libraries. 

If you really want Cloud Storage, you're going to have to roll your own proxy. Why aren't you using Firebase Storage? Its still another generally available Google service even if it isn't a Cloud branded service.

Comment: My confusion continues because Firebase Storage is backed by Cloud Storage. If I store something using Firebase Storage, I can go to the Google Cloud Platform console, navigate to Cloud Storage, and the bucket is there with the items added using Firebase Storage. I don't understand why it would be any different using GCS directly. My hesitation for using Firebase Storage is to avoid using as many different 3rd party services as possible, especially when certain features of Firebase can conflict with App Engine (such as Firebase listeners disabling App Engine's auto scaling).

Comment: Continuing from my last comment, I would ideally like to only use products provided by GCP if possible, just to make things easier. I understand Firebase does integrate pretty well with GCP, but it is not part of GCP, is not guaranteed like GCP, and adds another 3rd party layer that seems unnecessary.

Comment: Firebase's issue with App Engine autoscaling is around the real-time database and long-lived connections. In the case of Firebase Storage from Android, I don't believe that limitation is an issue. You can of course use GCS directly as my answer details. 

Lastly Firebase isn't a third party product. Google's Firebase is intended to help mobile developers use Cloud services and hide away the hard parts. You are welcome to do it the hard way of course.

Comment: Brett, I read your answer to mean one cannot use GCS directly from a mobile device. I've reread it and do not see where you say it is usable from a mobile client. Firebase is not part of GCP, and is described as such clearly in the documentation, and confirmed by GCP support. It integrates with GCP, but is not part of the platform. I don't think it can be seen as a way to access GCP resources in an easier way. To the question at hand, lets say I make a request to App Engine which in turn talks to GCS. What does App Engine return to the mobile client to enable it to download the media objects?

Comment: I didn't say you can't connect to Cloud Storage, I said you shouldn't do that as it directly communicate with Cloud Storage as it exposes your credentials if you're using a service account connection rather than end-user OAuth. Its a bad idea. The end-user OAuth likely isn't your situation as the user doesn't own the project.

When proxying between your App Engine backend and your mobile client, you could just return binary data of the object or you could return the Storage URL of the object assuming its stored as publicly linkable. Either works and just depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Also, Android isn't part of GCP either :)

Comment: Brett, I'm not sure what you were referencing with your last comment, but i'm quite aware Android is not part of GCP. Regardless, security issues aside, it seems the misleadingly named `Google Cloud Client library for Java` is not for use with Android. See an issue I posted on the repository: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1696

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing, but I *think* the Firebase Storage API is the way you're supposed to be doing this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Comment: I am not currently using Firebase anywhere in my application. I know Firebase Storage is backed by Google Cloud Storage, however Firebase is not a product of the Google Cloud Platform, and I highly doubt that is how you access your Cloud Storage buckets. I appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a late answer. But I think, it will be useful to someone.

Firstly, You should get the below information by registering your application in the GCP console.

```
private final String pkcsFile = "xxx.json";//private key file
private final String bucketName = "your_gcp_bucket_name";
private final String projectId = "your_gcp_project_id";
```

Once you get the credentials, you should put the private key (.p12 or .json) in your assets folder. I'm using JSON format private key file. Also, you should update the image location to upload.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void uploadImageFile(String srcFileName, String newName) {
            Storage storage = getStorage();

        File file = new File(srcFileName);//Your image loaction
        byte[] fileContent;
        try {
            fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        if (fileContent == null || fileContent.length == 0)
            return;
        BlobInfo.Builder newBuilder = Blob.newBuilder(BucketInfo.of(bucketName), newName);
        BlobInfo blobInfo = newBuilder.setContentType("image/png").build();
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, fileContent);
        String bucket = blob.getBucket();
        String contentType = blob.getContentType();
        Log.e("TAG", "Upload File: " + contentType);
        Log.e("File ", srcFileName + " uploaded to bucket " + bucket + " as " + newName);
    }

private Storage getStorage() {
        InputStream credentialsStream;
        Credentials credentials;

        try {
            credentialsStream = mContext.getAssets().open(pkcsFile);
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setProjectId(projectId).setCredentials(credentials)
                .build().getService();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who (as I did) came here looking for a simple and easy way to use anonymous transfers (i.e. without Firebase and everything that goes with that) to access an API, here's what I discovered after a full day's work...

1. Pull in the Google Cloud Storage library by adding these lines to the indicated sections of build.gradle. NB that the version is important. **Versions from 2.24.0 to the current latest 2.27.1 do not run.**

   ```
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "META-INF/INDEX.LIST"
        }
    }

   dependencies {
        implementation("com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.23.0")
   }
   ```
2. In MainActivity (or wherever), add these lines, obviously changing bucketName and publicObjectName values to your values.

NB: filesDir is a property of MainActivity that specifies what directory your files will be written to.

NB: Thread is needed because in later versions of Android it is not allowed to access the network from the UI thread.

```
val publicObjectName = "something.json"

Thread {

    val bucketName = "a long  -stri-ng  -of  -hexadecimal "

    val storage = StorageOptions.getUnauthenticatedInstance().service

    val blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, publicObjectName)

    val blob = storage[blobId]

    blob.downloadTo(File("${filesDir}/${publicObjectName}").toPath())

}.start()
```