# How to connect and use google cloud sql for database access?

Tags: android, sql-server, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I know this is a nooby question and I apologise in advance. I'm looking all over but I just can't seem to find any documentation on connecting an Android app built in Android Studio to a Google Cloud SQL Database.
I'm only really doing this to try and find out how it is done because I'm interested in it but I'm very new to Android development. I've connected to a SQL database before from c# but it was only a local one, I've never connected to an online one before and I think the Google Cloud Platform operates a bit differently anyway?
Basically, whenever I try to find documentation for this, it keeps referring back to the Google App Engine, which seems to be a different way to create apps than just writing them in Android Studio (very likely I could be wrong, like I said, I'm very new to Android development).
I've seen that there is documentation for Eclipse with the Google Plugin but can't find anything for Android Studio. Is Android Studio not suited for this type of use?
I've seen that you can create a Google Cloud module for a project in Android Studio but I'm not exactly sure what that entails.
Basically, I would just love a set of very basic steps that I should follow for if I were wanting to write to a Google Cloud SQL DB from an Android app in Android Studio.
Otherwise, any good resources where I could possibly learn more about what I need to do would also be appreciated.
I think my biggest issue currently is that I have exactly 0 backend knowledge and so I'm just not really sure of what is required to set up this connection.

Comment: You can not do it directly you need an app engine logic!

Comment: There is a way without App engine just a database but it also doesnt involve sql-sever. But easy to learn

Answer (score 1):

You should not access Cloud SQL directly from your Android (or iOS) or other client because you cannot secure the credentials needed to do so. If you embedded your credentials into your app, someone could extract them and either gain access to your database directly or could cause other trouble for you.

If you are open to other database types and you don't want to explore proxying requests through your own backend, then you should take a look at [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) or [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/). Firebase provides SDKs for Android that allow you to access these securely directly from your app. Firestore will scale better than the Realtime database, but that might not matter for your app.

A similar question and reason for why you shouldn't try to connect directly to Cloud SQL is [covered in more depth here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601917/accessing-cloud-storage-from-android/42611062#42611062).